# C# AddPicture to excel work sheet - System.Xml.XmlException: ''rId12' ID conflicts with the ID of an existing relationship for the specified source.'

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm trig to add a image to excel work sheet template using ClosedXML.But when save the worksheet, it's give this error. I use WPS office

System.Xml.XmlException: ''rId12' ID conflicts with the ID of an existing relationship for the specified source.'

My code-

```
var template = new XLTemplate(@ ".\Templates\Test.xlsx");
var ws = template.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "Overblik");
var imagePath = @ "D:\image.png";

var image = ws.AddPicture(imagePath)
.MoveTo(ws.Cell("F10"))
.Scale(0.5);

template.Generate();
template.Workbook.SaveAs("Test.xlsx");

using(var fms = new MemoryStream()) {
template.SaveAs(fms);
  fms.Position = 0;
}
```

I can't figure out the reason for the error and tried many ways to add the image and always returned the same error.